# Is it possible to list out the messages each queue is having in SQS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-sqs, nestjs

I am trying to use the aqs sqs for the queues and able to send post the questions as well following CRUD. Now with the following mentioned code I am listing the number of queues which I am having and now I want the number of messages each queue is having in the AWS SQS.

```
     const params = {};
           sqs.listQueues(params , (err, data) => {
           return !err ? resolve({data}) : reject (new HttpException(err, 500));
           });
        });`
```

I am able to list out all the queues. Suppose I got total 3 queues. Now I am planning to list out messages in each queue as well.

Like below the number of queues I got after using the listQueues method.

https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/82974853333/Aqueue

https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/82974853333/Bqueue

https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/82974853333/Cqueue

with each queue,having the number of messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain queue metrics from [Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sqs-metricscollected.html).

The best metric to use is: `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible`

Use [GetMetricStatistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricStatistics-property) to retrieve the metrics.